# JRuby and Swing Event Dispatch Thread

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, jruby

Java Swing tutorials use SwingUtilities.invokeLater to create the GUI (like [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html)). Why is this done is explained [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) - most Swing objects are not thread safe. On the other hand most JRuby Swing examples I've seen just set the top frame visible in the script (like [here](http://pragprog.com/titles/jruby/source_code) - the 'guis' directory in the archive).

The question is, should I follow the Java pattern of using SwingUtilities.invokeLater() when creating the application top frame in JRuby scripts?

I have two JRuby scripts, one that uses SwingUtilities.invokeLater() and one that doesn't:

```
java_import javax.swing.JFrame
java_import javax.swing.SwingUtilities
java_import java.awt.Dimension
java_import javax.swing.JButton
JavaThread = java.lang.Thread

class TopFrame < JFrame

  def initialize
    super
    init_components()

    pack()
    set_visible(true)

    puts '----------------------------------------'
    puts 'In JFrame constructor:'
    puts "Thread name: #{JavaThread.current_thread.name}"
    puts "Is event dispatch thread: #{SwingUtilities.event_dispatch_thread?}"
    JavaThread.current_thread.thread_group.list

  end

  def init_components()

    set_default_close_operation(JFrame::EXIT_ON_CLOSE)
    set_preferred_size(Dimension.new(400, 300))

    button = JButton.new('Button')
    button.add_action_listener do |event|
      puts '----------------------------------------'
      puts 'In action listener:'
      puts "Thread name: #{JavaThread.current_thread.name}"
      puts "Is event dispatch thread: #{SwingUtilities.event_dispatch_thread?}"
      JavaThread.current_thread.thread_group.list
    end

    get_content_pane.add(button)

  end

end

puts '----------------------------------------'
puts 'Before SwingUtilties.invokeLater():'
puts "Thread name: #{JavaThread.current_thread.name}"
puts "Is event dispatch thread: #{SwingUtilities.event_dispatch_thread?}"
JavaThread.current_thread.thread_group.list

SwingUtilities.invoke_later do
  TopFrame.new
end

puts '----------------------------------------'
puts 'After SwingUtilities.invokeLater():'
puts "Thread name: #{JavaThread.current_thread.name}"
puts "Is event dispatch thread: #{SwingUtilities.event_dispatch_thread?}"
JavaThread.current_thread.thread_group.list
```

The output is:

```
----------------------------------------
Before SwingUtilties.invokeLater():
Thread name: main
Is event dispatch thread: false
java.lang.ThreadGroup[name=main,maxpri=10]
    Thread[main,5,main]
    Thread[Ruby-0-JIT-1,1,main]
    java.lang.ThreadGroup[name=Ruby Threads#11483240,maxpri=10]
----------------------------------------
After SwingUtilities.invokeLater():
Thread name: main
Is event dispatch thread: false
java.lang.ThreadGroup[name=main,maxpri=10]
    Thread[main,5,main]
    Thread[Ruby-0-JIT-1,1,main]
    Thread[AWT-EventQueue-0,6,main]
    java.lang.ThreadGroup[name=Ruby Threads#11483240,maxpri=10]
----------------------------------------
In JFrame constructor:
Thread name: AWT-EventQueue-0
Is event dispatch thread: true
java.lang.ThreadGroup[name=main,maxpri=10]
    Thread[AWT-EventQueue-0,6,main]
    Thread[DestroyJavaVM,5,main]
    java.lang.ThreadGroup[name=Ruby Threads#11483240,maxpri=10]
----------------------------------------
In action listener:
Thread name: AWT-EventQueue-0
Is event dispatch thread: true
java.lang.ThreadGroup[name=main,maxpri=10]
    Thread[AWT-EventQueue-0,6,main]
    Thread[DestroyJavaVM,5,main]
    java.lang.ThreadGroup[name=Ruby Threads#11483240,maxpri=10]
```

Before SwingUtilities.invokeLater() is called the EDT doesn't exist After SwingUtilities.invokeLater() EDT exists and it's different than the current thread. In JFrame constructor and JButton action event listener EDT is the current thread.

The other script doesn't use SwingUtilities.invokeLater():

```
java_import javax.swing.JFrame
java_import javax.swing.SwingUtilities
java_import java.awt.Dimension
java_import javax.swing.JButton
JavaThread = java.lang.Thread

puts '----------------------------------------'
puts 'Before JFrame.new():'
puts "Thread name: #{JavaThread.current_thread.name}"
puts "Is event dispatch thread: #{SwingUtilities.event_dispatch_thread?}"
JavaThread.current_thread.thread_group.list

frame = JFrame.new()

frame.set_default_close_operation(JFrame::EXIT_ON_CLOSE)
frame.set_preferred_size(Dimension.new(400, 300))

button = JButton.new('Button')
button.add_action_listener do |event|
  puts '----------------------------------------'
  puts 'In action listener:'
  puts "Thread name: #{JavaThread.current_thread.name}"
  puts "Is event dispatch thread: #{SwingUtilities.event_dispatch_thread?}"
  JavaThread.current_thread.thread_group.list
end

frame.get_content_pane.add(button)
frame.pack()

puts '----------------------------------------'
puts 'Before JFrame.setVisible():'
puts "Thread name: #{JavaThread.current_thread.name}"
puts "Is event dispatch thread: #{SwingUtilities.event_dispatch_thread?}"
JavaThread.current_thread.thread_group.list

frame.set_visible(true)
```

The output is:

```
----------------------------------------
Before JFrame.new():
Thread name: main
Is event dispatch thread: false
java.lang.ThreadGroup[name=main,maxpri=10]
    Thread[main,5,main]
    Thread[Ruby-0-JIT-1,1,main]
    java.lang.ThreadGroup[name=Ruby Threads#11483240,maxpri=10]
----------------------------------------
Before JFrame.setVisible():
Thread name: main
Is event dispatch thread: false
java.lang.ThreadGroup[name=main,maxpri=10]
    Thread[main,5,main]
    Thread[Ruby-0-JIT-1,1,main]
    Thread[AWT-EventQueue-0,6,main]
    java.lang.ThreadGroup[name=Ruby Threads#11483240,maxpri=10]
----------------------------------------
In action listener:
Thread name: AWT-EventQueue-0
Is event dispatch thread: true
java.lang.ThreadGroup[name=main,maxpri=10]
    Thread[AWT-EventQueue-0,6,main]
    Thread[DestroyJavaVM,5,main]
    java.lang.ThreadGroup[name=Ruby Threads#11483240,maxpri=10]
```

EDT is created after JFrame constructor is not the current thread. In JButton event listener EDT is the current thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

consider JRuby as any other JVM language ... with no special care for Swing/AWT conventions built-in - only a "new" syntax for writing a Swing GUI. as such do care about EDT just like you would in Java.